# Remove duplicated from ONLY FIRST column in DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, datatable, mdx

I have a DataTable containing 10 rows and 2 columns which is created from a mdx query, I want to convert this DataTable into html table but before that I want remove duplicated from ONLY FIRST column.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ and query it yourself:

```
myTable.Tables[0].Rows.GroupBy(x => x["Column1Name"]);
```

Your rows should now be grouped by a distinct Column1Name value, and you can then access it from there.